# 96 Civic EX overheating

Tags: overheating, head-gasket, oil-in-coolant

so i bought a 96 civic last week and it ran good for the test drive but lo and behold it over heats after a while. i will drive for like 30 mins and i will get an oil pressure light at idle. i give it a little gas and it goes away. i replaced spark plugs and found one of my wires was broken so got a new set of those. i just put new oil in and it seemed to fix it. after a few days the light came back and i then found i didnt have any coolant. i replaced the thermostat and refilled it with distilled water for now (dont feel like bleeding coolant multiple times lol) its not overly frustrating until i seem to lose power in first gear under 5k rpm. as of tonight i just did a combustion leak test with the blue liquid stuff and am kinda stumped. any help is appreciated

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! What exactly is your question here? Which part are you trying to solve?

Comment: check thermostat,have you connected a obd II and checked codes, part stores sell bad parts.

Comment: i will go ahead and check the thermostat as this is the 3rd suggestion across everywhere i asked that i've got a faulty one i will get codes checked and thermostat checked and report back

Comment: and to reply to Paulster i am trying to find out what needs to be fixed  i know not a ton about cars but spent all winter rebuilding a motorcycle so im not like mechanically inept

Comment: Just got off and tested the thermostat and it's. the car runs okay for like 40-45 mins and then i get a faint flicker of the oil pressure light at idle/ N.